# Mass Points: When does the centroid of the triangle formed by the cevians coincide with the original triangle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I'm studying mass points and I stumbled upon this problem:

"Consider $\Delta ABC$ with points $P, Q, R$ on $AB, BC, AC$ with $AP:PB=BQ:QC = CR:RA$. Then the centroid of the triangle formed by $AQ, BR, CP$ coincides with the centroid of the original triangle $\Delta ABC$."

I was able to solve it using mass points. I'm wondering whether the converse is true and whether it's possible to prove it using mass points:

"Consider $\Delta ABC$ with points $P, Q, R$ on $AB, BC, AC$. If the centroid of the triangle formed by $AQ, BR, CP$ coincides with the centroid of the original triangle $\Delta ABC$, then $AP:PB=BQ:QC = CR:RA$."

Edit: There was a request for clarification. The triangle formed by $AQ, BR, CP$ is the triangle formed when the three cevians are drawn. If they do not all intersect at the same point, they form a triangle.

Comment: Can you explain what is "centroid of the triangle formed by ,,"? Do you mean triangle QRP instead?

Comment: I added an edit at the end of the post, hopefully, it clarifies things.